# Fallout Board Game: How to resolve card 16

Tags: fallout

Card 16, "All Aboard", has a condition "Place the third shield on the map".

This is the condition to complete this quest, so how can I as a player complete this condition? What third shield? Place it how? Place it where on the map?

[image]

Comment: This card is the prime example of one of the biggest stumbling blocks in this game IMO: cards usually don't spell out exactly how certain things are done. Don't get me wrong, I like the game quite a bit. However it takes a lot of getting used to since as far as I can tell there are many similar scenarios which are incredibly vague and not directly written in the rulebook, but they largely resolve in similar manners (i.e. the encounter decks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing as I haven't played the game or read the rules.

It appears as though in order to place the shield you need to contact the Institute locations at that icon I can't quite make out.

Edit: Did some research, this link appears to say you should have added an additional institute location to the map in the previous quest?  https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1893927/quest-states-simply-place-icon-map

Answer (score 2):

With this quest out, there should be at least 2 shield tokens. You also added 17 to it's deck, which gives you a way to get the third one out.